# I see a contradiction in these 3 statements. Am I wrong?

Tags: probability

The exact text of the exercise:

> A conservative design team, call it C, and an innovative design team,
>   call it N, are asked to **separately** design a new product within a
>   month. From past experience we know that:
>
> - The probability that team C is successful is 2/3.
> - The probability that team N is successful is 1/2.
> - The probability that at least one team is successful is 3/4.

The exercise then continues, but I have a problem with all 3 of these statements being true. The reason is the following: Pr(C fails) = 1/3. Pr(N fails) = 1/2. C fails and N fails are independent events (they are asked to design separately),
so Pr(C fails and N fails) = Pr(C fails) * Pr(N fails) = 1/3 * 1/2 = 1/6. Therefore, Pr(atleast one success) = Pr(not both fail) = 1 - 1/6 = 5/6,
which contradicts the 3rd statement. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Who says they are independent?  If a project is hard, maybe they are both more likely to fail.  If a project is easy, maybe they are both more likely to succeed.

Comment: Independent is what I guess the authors mean when they say "... to separately design...". What else could it mean?

Comment: It means they aren't working together.  It certainly doesn't mean that the outcomes are independent variables.

Comment: Here's a sensible example.  Suppose team $N$ isn't very good.  They can do the easy projects but fail at all the hard ones.  Team $C$ is better.  They can do all the easy ones AND they can do a third of the hard ones.  That would satisfy the first two assumptions, though we'd get a probability of $\frac 23$ for the third condition (since team $N$ here is basically irrelevant).  To match all three assumptions, you need there to be some tasks $N$ can do that $C$ can't, in addition to the other way round.

Comment: @lulu Oh, it clicked! This answers the question!